# Curl comand does not work after runing the docker file

Tags: docker

I have a script shell code named job.sh  that contains the following curl comand:

```
curl http://httpbin.org/user-agent
```

When i execute the script on my ubuntu Terminal, every thing works fine.
Using the cmnd "docker build" I build my docker file and the build works fine also.
But when I run the docker the curl comand is not executed and I get the following error : "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL".

My docker file is like this :

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./job.sh /
RUN chmod +x /job.sh
RUN apk update \
 && apk add curl 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/job.sh"]
CMD [""]
```

My script job.sh is like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://httpbin.org/user-agent
```

Thanks a lot for the help,

Comment: There may be some illegal chars in you actual script. If you have copied it, you can write it yourself or check it with commands like `hexdump -C FILENAME`

Comment: Try it without the last line in the dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Just use quotes for url:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl "http://httpbin.org/user-agent"
```